# SOAP - unable to invoke since upgrade to 1.9.3.1 (timeout), how to debug?

Tags: soap, soap-api-v2, soap-api-v1, magento1.9.3.1, ce-1.9.3.1

I've recently upgraded a Magento installation from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.1. Ever since, the various apps I use to communicate with Magento via SOAPv2 have timed out with error 504.

When I attempt to load the WSDL in .NET WebService Studio I can see a complete listing of all the services, but when I attempt to invoke any of the services the process times out.

I've attempted using the SOAPv1 API and I'm getting exactly the same issue.

I've also tried installed a completely fresh copy of Magento, and the result is exactly the same; WSDL loads but times out when any invoke is attempted.
The only log I can find which is even vaguely helpful is PHP-FPM's slow process log, which reveals this trace:

```
SoapServer() /web-root/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php:814
_getSoap() /web-root/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php:880
handle() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/S$
run() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php:138
run() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/V2/SoapControlle$
indexAction() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/A$
dispatch() /web-root/var/cache/ew/files/69/b9/Mage/Core/Controller/$
match() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.p$
dispatch() /web-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
run() /web-root/app/Mage.php:684
run() /web-root/index.php:116
```

How can I debug what the problem might be?

What might have changed between 1.9.0.1 and 1.9.3.1 which would clash with the server?

Comment: I've tried disabling all extensions except Mage_ ones and I'm getting the same issue. Timeout, no error to debug.

Comment: Still working on this - PHP FPM's slow process logs reveals the timeout occurs after session_start - see edit to main post if it helps any!

Comment: I've now tried a fresh installation of Mage 1.9.3.1 and I'm getting the exact same problem so it must be something to do with my server configuration, any ideas on where to start looking?

Comment: Not sure this helps any, but the access log reveals a 500 server error when SOAP is POSTed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by 500 errors as a result of duplicate headers.

The fix is detailed here: http://www.magegyver.de/duplicate-content-type-header-on-api-responses/

To get things working I copied

app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php

to

app/code/local/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php

and edited lines 62 and 85 from:

```
->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=' . $apiConfigCharset)
```

to:

```
->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=' . $apiConfigCharset, true)
```